# Magento Cookie issue on AWS EC2 and ELB

Tags: magento, cookies, amazon-ec2

My site is working on AWS two EC2 servers via ELB. I setup `'Enable load balancer generated cookie stickiness'` in ELB to Magento work because without this add to cart is not working. Now issue is I used some code to track recent view products on website via cookie. I am using array of product IDS in below code

```
Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('viewedProducts', $raw, time()+3600*24*7);
```

But not this function is not working after move to AWS EB2 ELB setup. On single server is was working.

Please help to get this fixed. We can't change ELB sickness setting because add to cart will not work.

Anyone please help me.